# Debian:unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies

Just trying to install xfce4 on Debian Jessie but I get unmet dependencies error:

```
root@iPig:~# apt-get install xfce4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xfce4 : Depends: xfce4-panel (>= 4.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gtk2-engines-xfce (>= 3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: xfce4-mixer (>= 4.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: orage (>= 4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@iPig:~#
```

I have googoled a lot and I couldn't find any useful hint.
Any idea how fix the problem? Let me know if you need for more info

Running aptitude, this is the output

```
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-data.
(Reading database ... 100196 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-data_2.4.10-10+deb8u5_all.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-data (2.4.10-10+deb8u5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-utils_2.4.10-10+deb8u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-utils (2.4.10-10+deb8u5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package colord-data.
Preparing to unpack .../colord-data_1.2.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking colord-data (1.2.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-atk-1.0.
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-atk-1.0_2.14.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-atk-1.0 (2.14.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0.
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0_2.31.1-2+deb8u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (2.31.1-2+deb8u5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package glib-networking-common.
Preparing to unpack .../glib-networking-common_2.42.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking glib-networking-common (2.42.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ipmitool.
Preparing to unpack .../ipmitool_1.8.14-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ipmitool (1.8.14-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-c3-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-c3-perl_0.09-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-c3-perl (0.09-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.5.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-ldap:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libarchive-extract-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libarchive-extract-perl_0.72-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libarchive-extract-perl (0.72-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-pm-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libcgi-pm-perl_4.09-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-pm-perl (4.09-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libuniversal-require-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libuniversal-require-perl_0.17-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libuniversal-require-perl (0.17-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-untaint-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libcgi-untaint-perl_1.26-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-untaint-perl (1.26-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libclass-c3-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libclass-c3-perl_0.26-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libclass-c3-perl (0.26-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfile-nfslock-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libfile-nfslock-perl_1.24-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libfile-nfslock-perl (1.24-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjson-glib-1.0-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libjson-glib-1.0-common_1.0.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libjson-glib-1.0-common (1.0.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblog-message-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../liblog-message-perl_0.8-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liblog-message-perl (0.8-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblog-message-simple-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../liblog-message-simple-perl_0.10-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking liblog-message-simple-perl (0.10-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmath-calc-units-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libmath-calc-units-perl_1.07-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmath-calc-units-perl (1.07-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmodule-pluggable-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libmodule-pluggable-perl_5.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmodule-pluggable-perl (5.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmodule-signature-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libmodule-signature-perl_0.73-1+deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmodule-signature-perl (0.73-1+deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmro-compat-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libmro-compat-perl_0.12-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmro-compat-perl (0.12-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnet-ip-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libnet-ip-perl_1.26-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnet-ip-perl (1.26-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpackage-constants-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libpackage-constants-perl_0.04-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libpackage-constants-perl (0.04-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpod-readme-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libpod-readme-perl_0.11-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libpod-readme-perl (0.11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsub-install-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libsub-install-perl_0.928-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libsub-install-perl (0.928-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libterm-ui-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libterm-ui-perl_0.42-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libterm-ui-perl (0.42-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.50-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.50-0+deb8u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php5-mysql.
Preparing to unpack .../php5-mysql_5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php5-mysql (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ploticus.
Preparing to unpack .../ploticus_2.42-3+b2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ploticus (2.42-3+b2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-ipaddr.
Preparing to unpack .../python-ipaddr_2.1.11-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-ipaddr (2.1.11-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-libvirt.
Preparing to unpack .../python-libvirt_1.2.9-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-libvirt (1.2.9-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-libxml2.
Preparing to unpack .../python-libxml2_2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-libxml2 (2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-mysqldb.
Preparing to unpack .../python-mysqldb_1.2.3-2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-mysqldb (1.2.3-2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pycurl.
Preparing to unpack .../python-pycurl_7.19.5-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-pycurl (7.19.5-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-urlgrabber.
Preparing to unpack .../python-urlgrabber_3.9.1-4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-urlgrabber (3.9.1-4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xrdp.
Preparing to unpack .../xrdp_0.6.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xrdp (0.6.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtext-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libtext-template-perl_1.46-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtext-template-perl (1.46-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtinst.
Preparing to unpack .../virtinst_1%3a1.0.1-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtinst (1:1.0.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for manSelecting previously unselected package apache2-data.
(Reading database ... 100196 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-data_2.4.10-10+deb8u5_all.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-data (2.4.10-10+deb8u5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-utils_2.4.10-10+deb8u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-utils (2.4.10-10+deb8u5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package colord-data.
Preparing to unpack .../colord-data_1.2.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking colord-data (1.2.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-atk-1.0.
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-atk-1.0_2.14.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-atk-1.0 (2.14.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0.
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0_2.31.1-2+deb8u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (2.31.1-2+deb8u5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package glib-networking-common.
Preparing to unpack .../glib-networking-common_2.42.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking glib-networking-common (2.42.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ipmitool.
Preparing to unpack .../ipmitool_1.8.14-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ipmitool (1.8.14-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-c3-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-c3-perl_0.09-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-c3-perl (0.09-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.5.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-ldap:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libarchive-extract-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libarchive-extract-perl_0.72-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libarchive-extract-perl (0.72-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-pm-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libcgi-pm-perl_4.09-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-pm-perl (4.09-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libuniversal-require-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libuniversal-require-perl_0.17-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libuniversal-require-perl (0.17-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-untaint-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libcgi-untaint-perl_1.26-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-untaint-perl (1.26-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libclass-c3-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libclass-c3-perl_0.26-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libclass-c3-perl (0.26-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfile-nfslock-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libfile-nfslock-perl_1.24-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libfile-nfslock-perl (1.24-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjson-glib-1.0-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libjson-glib-1.0-common_1.0.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libjson-glib-1.0-common (1.0.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblog-message-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../liblog-message-perl_0.8-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liblog-message-perl (0.8-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblog-message-simple-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../liblog-message-simple-perl_0.10-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking liblog-message-simple-perl (0.10-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmath-calc-units-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libmath-calc-units-perl_1.07-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmath-calc-units-perl (1.07-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmodule-pluggable-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libmodule-pluggable-perl_5.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmodule-pluggable-perl (5.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmodule-signature-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libmodule-signature-perl_0.73-1+deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmodule-signature-perl (0.73-1+deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmro-compat-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libmro-compat-perl_0.12-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libmro-compat-perl (0.12-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnet-ip-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libnet-ip-perl_1.26-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnet-ip-perl (1.26-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpackage-constants-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libpackage-constants-perl_0.04-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libpackage-constants-perl (0.04-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpod-readme-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libpod-readme-perl_0.11-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libpod-readme-perl (0.11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsub-install-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libsub-install-perl_0.928-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libsub-install-perl (0.928-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libterm-ui-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libterm-ui-perl_0.42-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libterm-ui-perl (0.42-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.50-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.50-0+deb8u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php5-mysql.
Preparing to unpack .../php5-mysql_5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php5-mysql (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ploticus.
Preparing to unpack .../ploticus_2.42-3+b2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ploticus (2.42-3+b2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-ipaddr.
Preparing to unpack .../python-ipaddr_2.1.11-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-ipaddr (2.1.11-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-libvirt.
Preparing to unpack .../python-libvirt_1.2.9-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-libvirt (1.2.9-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-libxml2.
Preparing to unpack .../python-libxml2_2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-libxml2 (2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-mysqldb.
Preparing to unpack .../python-mysqldb_1.2.3-2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-mysqldb (1.2.3-2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pycurl.
Preparing to unpack .../python-pycurl_7.19.5-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-pycurl (7.19.5-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-urlgrabber.
Preparing to unpack .../python-urlgrabber_3.9.1-4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-urlgrabber (3.9.1-4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xrdp.
Preparing to unpack .../xrdp_0.6.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xrdp (0.6.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtext-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libtext-template-perl_1.46-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtext-template-perl (1.46-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtinst.
Preparing to unpack .../virtinst_1%3a1.0.1-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtinst (1:1.0.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for php5-fpm (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Setting up apache2-data (2.4.10-10+deb8u5) ...
Setting up apache2-utils (2.4.10-10+deb8u5) ...
Setting up colord-data (1.2.1-1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-atk-1.0 (2.14.0-1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (2.31.1-2+deb8u5) ...
Setting up glib-networking-common (2.42.0-2) ...
Setting up ipmitool (1.8.14-4) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-c3-perl (0.09-1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.4-1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.4-1) ...
Setting up libarchive-extract-perl (0.72-1) ...
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.09-1) ...
Setting up libuniversal-require-perl (0.17-1) ...
Setting up libcgi-untaint-perl (1.26-5) ...
Setting up libclass-c3-perl (0.26-1) ...
Setting up libfile-nfslock-perl (1.24-1) ...
Setting up libjson-glib-1.0-common (1.0.2-1) ...
Setting up liblog-message-perl (0.8-1) ...
Setting up liblog-message-simple-perl (0.10-2) ...
Setting up libmath-calc-units-perl (1.07-1) ...
Setting up libmodule-pluggable-perl (5.1-1) ...
Setting up libmodule-signature-perl (0.73-1+deb8u2) ...
Setting up libmro-compat-perl (0.12-1) ...
Setting up libnet-ip-perl (1.26-1) ...
Setting up libpackage-constants-perl (0.04-1) ...
Setting up libpod-readme-perl (0.11-1) ...
Setting up libsub-install-perl (0.928-1) ...
Setting up libterm-ui-perl (0.42-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.50-0+deb8u1) ...
Setting up php5-mysql (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini with new version
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for cli SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for fpm SAPI

Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/mysqli.ini with new version
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for cli SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for fpm SAPI

Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini with new version
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for cli SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for fpm SAPI
Setting up ploticus (2.42-3+b2) ...
Setting up python-ipaddr (2.1.11-2) ...
Setting up python-libvirt (1.2.9-1) ...
Setting up python-libxml2 (2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u2) ...
Setting up python-mysqldb (1.2.3-2.1) ...
Setting up python-pycurl (7.19.5-3) ...
Setting up python-urlgrabber (3.9.1-4.1) ...
Setting up xrdp (0.6.1-2) ...
Setting up libtext-template-perl (1.46-1) ...
Setting up virtinst (1:1.0.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for php5-fpm (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for python-support (1.0.15) ...
Press Return to continue.

root@iPig:~# apt-get install xfce4-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for php5-fpm (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Setting up apache2-data (2.4.10-10+deb8u5) ...
Setting up apache2-utils (2.4.10-10+deb8u5) ...
Setting up colord-data (1.2.1-1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-atk-1.0 (2.14.0-1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (2.31.1-2+deb8u5) ...
Setting up glib-networking-common (2.42.0-2) ...
Setting up ipmitool (1.8.14-4) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-c3-perl (0.09-1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.4-1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.4-1) ...
Setting up libarchive-extract-perl (0.72-1) ...
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.09-1) ...
Setting up libuniversal-require-perl (0.17-1) ...
Setting up libcgi-untaint-perl (1.26-5) ...
Setting up libclass-c3-perl (0.26-1) ...
Setting up libfile-nfslock-perl (1.24-1) ...
Setting up libjson-glib-1.0-common (1.0.2-1) ...
Setting up liblog-message-perl (0.8-1) ...
Setting up liblog-message-simple-perl (0.10-2) ...
Setting up libmath-calc-units-perl (1.07-1) ...
Setting up libmodule-pluggable-perl (5.1-1) ...
Setting up libmodule-signature-perl (0.73-1+deb8u2) ...
Setting up libmro-compat-perl (0.12-1) ...
Setting up libnet-ip-perl (1.26-1) ...
Setting up libpackage-constants-perl (0.04-1) ...
Setting up libpod-readme-perl (0.11-1) ...
Setting up libsub-install-perl (0.928-1) ...
Setting up libterm-ui-perl (0.42-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.50-0+deb8u1) ...
Setting up php5-mysql (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini with new version
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for cli SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for fpm SAPI

Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/mysqli.ini with new version
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for cli SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for fpm SAPI

Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini with new version
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for cli SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for fpm SAPI
Setting up ploticus (2.42-3+b2) ...
Setting up python-ipaddr (2.1.11-2) ...
Setting up python-libvirt (1.2.9-1) ...
Setting up python-libxml2 (2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u2) ...
Setting up python-mysqldb (1.2.3-2.1) ...
Setting up python-pycurl (7.19.5-3) ...
Setting up python-urlgrabber (3.9.1-4.1) ...
Setting up xrdp (0.6.1-2) ...
Setting up libtext-template-perl (1.46-1) ...
Setting up virtinst (1:1.0.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for php5-fpm (5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for python-support (1.0.15) ...
Press Return to continue.

root@iPig:~# apt-get install xfce4
```

apt-cache policy xfce4 output

```
root@iPig:~# apt-cache policy xfce4
xfce4:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.10.1
  Version table:
     4.10.1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

apt-cache policy

```
root@iPig:~# apt-cache policy 
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin httpredir.debian.org
 500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main Translation-en
 500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin httpredir.debian.org
Pinned packages:
     pdns-recursor -> (not found)
     pdns-backend-mydns -> (not found)
     pdns-backend-mysql -> (not found)
     pdns-backend-geo -> (not found)
     dnsdist -> (not found)
     pdns-backend-sqlite3 -> (not found)
     pdns-server -> (not found)
     pdns-server-dbg -> (not found)
     pdns-backend-pipe -> (not found)
     pdns-backend-remote -> (not found)
     pdns-backend -> (not found)
     pdns-backend-lua -> (not found)
     pdns-backend-ldap -> (not found)
     pdns-doc -> (not found)
     pdns-recursor-dbg -> (not found)
     pdns-backend-pgsql -> (not found)
     pdns-backend-lmdb -> (not found)
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy xfce4`

Comment: Could you add the output of `apt-cache policy`?

Comment: Let's have `apt-cache policy xfce4-panel gtk2-engines-xfce xfce4-mixer orage`.

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install xfce4
```

**Edit**

```
aptitude remove xfce4-panel gtk2-engines-xfce xfce4-mixer orage
aptitude -f install xfce4-panel gtk2-engines-xfce xfce4-mixer orage
aptitude install xfce4
```

Comment: Done.Same problem.

Comment: Run `aptitude` then press `u`  key then `g` key and validate with enter

Comment: Ok,It found something to be fixed and it updated everything however...still the problem (see update on description)

Comment: Still the problem!

Comment: ...still the problem :(

Comment: root@iPig:~# apt-get build-dep xfce4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

..still. Maybe Is better if I re-install Debian!